# Running multiple virtual directories on IIS - any performance issues?

Tags: iis, iis-6

I need to run 8-10 instances of my application on IIS 6.0 that are all identical but point to different backends (handled via config files, which would be different for each virtual directory).  I want to create multiple virtual directories that point to different versions of the app and I want to know if there is any significant performance penalty for this.  The server (Windows Server 2003) is a quad-core with 4 GB of ram and the single install of the app barely touches the CPU or memory, so it doesn't seem to be a concern.  This doesn't seem to justify another server, especially since some of the instances will be very lightly used.  Obviously, performance depends on the server and the application, but are there any concerns with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS on Windows Server 2003 is built to handle lots of sites, so the number of sites itself is not a concern. The resource needs of your application is much more of a factor. I.e., How much, i/o, cpu, threads, database resources does it consume?

We have a quad-core Windows Server 2003 server here handling several hundred sites no problem. But one resource-intensive app can eat a whole server no problem.

If you find your application is cpu bound, you can put each instance in its own application pool and then limit the amount of cpu each pool can use, so that no one instance can bottleneck any of the others.

I suggest you add a few at a time and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

No concerns. If you run into any performance issues, it won't be with IIS for 10 apps that size.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using multiple application pool. If you do that, and the cpu, memory, IO and network resources of the server are in order. Then there is no performance issue.

It is possible to run them all on the same application pool. But then add to the list, thread pool usage issue, because all application will use one thread pool, and if it is 32 bit server Then there is a limit( around 1.5 Gb ) for the w3wp process.

Answer (score 1):

We constantly run 15-20 per server on a 10 server load balanced farm.  We don't come across any issues

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, there should be no concerns.

In effect, you are asking if IIS can host 8 - 10 websites... of course it can. Perhaps, you might want to configure it as individual websites rather than virtual directories, and perhaps with individual application pools so that each instance is entirely independent.

You mention that these aren't vary demanding applications; assuming they aren't all linking into the same Access database, I can't see any problems.